# When wamp server is installed, is php installing automatically?

Tags: php, wamp

When we install wamp or xamp , is php installed on our pc automatically? since wamp means windows/apache/mysql/php 
can anyone explain it?

Comment: Yes. But if you don't start the services, it will not work. You have the option to manually start the services and automatically start the services whenever windows starts.

Comment: Yes, They all will be installed. first you should start each service you need. then you can access them in `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` address. put a `.php` file in your `www` directory and then you can access file in your local host. or if you want to access mysql database, first start the service and then go to `localhost/phpmyadmin` default user/pass is `root`

Comment: What color is your WAMPServer icon in the system tray? Red / Orange / Green?

Comment: when clicked  start all services , it turns from red to green

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, php comes with wamp and when you install wamp server on your pc, php also get installed. you can start php and other services automatically or manually, its upto you.

Comment: how to start it automatically,the way now i'm doing it manually by clicking start all the services on wamp icon

Comment: I think you are having port problem.
step 1: goto Wamp>Apache
step 2: open httpd.conf
step 3:find and change all port number from 80 to 8080
step 4:save and restart wamp

Comment: @SumitPal It would be better to first work out if the Apache port number is actually part of the problem!!! `wampmanager->Apache->Test port 80`